# What is the difference between 「登録している」 and 「登録した」?

Tags: verbs, tense

I got these verbs from the instruction manual of Nintendo 3DS when forgetting password to access a function.

メールアドレスを**登録している**ときは、マスターキーの送信画面で「OK」をタッチしてください。

**登録した**メールアドレスにマスターキーが送信されます。

**登録している**メールアドレスで受信拒否設定をしている場合は、@nintendo.netからのメールを受信可能な設定にしておいてください。

I think their meanings are the same, registered e-mail address, but I don't know the difference from using these 2 forms in this situation.

Comment: I posted an answer but I just noticed that you probably are more interested to know the difference between the second and third example, while in my answer below I was referring mostly to the first and second. Actually it's a good question. My gut feeling is that there is not much difference if not that in the progressive form you're emphasizing that the email is currently still registered (while with the past the email at the time of speaking might still be registered as well as it might not). However, I will leave it to more competent people to answer. I will delete my original answer.

Comment: 1: If you have already registered e-mail address, please touch "OK" in sending page of master key. 2: Master key will be sent to the e-mail address you have just registered. 3: In case, you have the setting for not receiving the  e-mail, please enable the setting to receive the e-mail from @nintendo.net.

Answer (score 3):

> "している" has two ways to be used.
>   1) present progressive form: Now you are doing something.
>   2) continuous form: You had done something and the situation had been changed. Now the situation has been continued.

---

> (OK: doing) メールアドレスを登録しているときは、マスターキーの送信画面で「OK」をタッチしてください。
>   When you are making registration of your mail address, you can submit the mail address registration form by cliking the "OK" icon.

---

> (NG or OK) メールアドレスを登録したときは、マスターキーの送信画面で「OK」をタッチしてください。

(NG) If you understand "メールアドレスを登録したとき" as "メールアドレス登録のformを送信したとき," "when you have finished submitting the registration" then the context should be "When you have finished submitting the registration of your mail adress, click the "OK" icon on the sending screen (to submit the registration.)"
It done not make sense.

(OK) If you understad "メールアドレスを登録したとき" as "メールアドレス登録に必要な事項の登録(input)を完了したとき", "when you have filled all the necessary column," the context should be "When you have filled all the necesary column, then all you have to do is to click the "OK" icon to submit it.

---

> (OK) 登録したメールアドレスにマスターキーが送信されます。
>   The master key will be sent to the registered mail adress.
>   (OK) 登録しているメールアドレスにマスターキーが送信されます。
>   (OK-1, doing) The master key will be sent to the mail address that you're now making regstration. (You have not finished it, but once you have finished it, the server system will send the master key to the mail address.)
>   (OK-2, status)　The master key will be sent to the registered mail address.
>
> (OK) 登録しているメールアドレスで受信拒否設定をしている場合は、@nintendo.netからのメールを受信可能な設定にしておいてください。
>   "登録している" = status:"registered"
>   (OK) 登録したメールアドレスで受信拒否設定をしている場合は、@nintendo.netからのメールを受信可能な設定にしておいてください。
>   "登録した" = action: "you had registered" = "the registration is still effective"

Answer (score 0):

> メールアドレスを**登録している**ときは、マスターキーの送信画面で「OK」をタッチしてください。

This sentence is establishing a condition from the perspective of you, the person who has registered the email address. So, in this case 登録し**ている** is used to indicate the condition where you have *finished the process* of registering your email address.

> **登録した**メールアドレスにマスターキーが送信されます。

This sentence is talking about what you should do with the email address *that you already finished registering*. So, **登録した**メールアドレス is acting like an adjectival phrase defining which mail address the マスターキー will be sent to.

> **登録している**メールアドレスで受信拒否設定をしている場合は、@nintendo.netからのメールを受信可能な設定にしておいてください。

「登録しているメールアドレス」combines the above. So in this case し**ている** is used to show that the email address that is being referred to is the one that is *in the state of having been registered* by you.

Summary:

- **ている** is being used to describe either being ***in a state*** or ***in a process***.

  「メールアドレスを登録しているときは」(*in a process*)
  「登録しているメールアドレス」(*in a state*)
- **た** is being used to show that the process ***has finished*** or ***is completed***.

  「登録したメールアドレス」
- Putting the verb before a noun or noun-phrase serves to define that noun or noun-phrase similar to an adjective.

  「登録しているとき」&「登録したメールアドレス」&「登録しているメールアドレス」

Comment: [ここ](https://www.nintendo.co.jp/support/3ds/pdf/3dsllmanual_20140513.pdf)（マニュアルの83ページ）を見ても分かるように、1文目の「メールアドレスを登録しているときは、」の「している」は、「今登録しているprocessにある」、という意味ではなくて、「すでに登録しているメールアドレスがある場合は」(you have registered and still have it)、って意味です。がんばって！＾＾

Comment: そこ迷っていたな！まいど m(＿＿)m

Comment: 「メールアドレスを登録しているときは」は、確かに２通りの意味に取れます。いずれの意味かは文脈で判断する必要があり面倒です。読み手を迷わさない確実な方法は、「（１）メールアドレスを **既に** 登録しているときは」あるいは「（２）メールアドレスを登録して **ある**ときは」です。読み手の立場に立って文を書くのが正しい言葉遣いです。